# Java: подсчёт количества определённых слов

Tags: java, строки

Как посчитать количество слов "привет" в строке на Java?

Comment: Вам нужно подсчитать количество именно _слов_, или количество вхождений _подстроки_? Какой ответ ожидается от следующих строк: "пппривет", "привет, валет", "ПРИвет"?

Comment: Именно слов.

Comment: Вот, правда "Привет" с большой буквы...

   Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^\\p{L}]+");
   String ar[] = p.split(str);
   for(i=0, count=0; i < ar.length; i++) 
       if(a[i].equals("Привет")) count++;

Comment: @alexlz, эффективнее искать само слово «привет»- это же регулярные выражения. Они могут почти все при работе с текстом.  

    \\bпривет\\b
с флагом игнора регистра.  
Нужно посчитать количество вхождений этого выражения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String str = "1100011";
int countNulls=0, countOnes = 0;
for (char element : str.toCharArray()){
    if (element == '0') countNulls++;
    if (element == '1') countOnes++;
}
```

Примерно такой принцип, только вы предложение разбиваете методом split(), и массив полученных данных подставляете вместо "str.toCharArray()" и тип не "char", а стринг, в теле пишете своё слово "привет", это более проще чем с регулярными выражениями, хотя я очень люблю регулярки)))

Answer (score 5):

[[@ReinRaus](/users/481/reinraus)](/users/481/reinraus) насчёт эффективности -- согласен. А так -- как хотите:

```
    int count = 0;
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\bПривет\\b", Pattern.UNICODE_CASE|Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    while(m.find()) count++;
```

Кто-то в ответ перевёл, пока исправлял комментарий...

Answer (score -2):

распарси строку на слова и сравнивай каждое слово с "привет"
Сколько раз встретишь - столько и вхождений слова в строку)